# Bison/Flex parser getting strings as token values

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I am currently working on a verilog parser using bison and flex as the tokenizer. My grammar works fine and now my goal is to store the data collected in a database.
(If you don't know what verilog is, it doesn't really matter but you can find info here : http://www.verilog.com/VerilogBNF.html)

I am currently stuck on getting the token values. My grammar mainly consists of strings and some numbers.

I browsed the internet and find usefull stuff that lead me tu write this kind of lex rules :

```
[A-Za-z_]+[A-Za-z0-9_$]* {
    lline = yylineno;yylval.str = strdup(yytext);
    return K_IDENTIFIER;
}
```

In my bison input file .y I made some adjustments that are

```
#define YYSTYPE char*
....
%union {char* str;
  double val;
}
%token<str>K_IDENTIFIER
...
beginning of the grammar rules
```

Now, when i have a grammar rule that has a K_IDENTIFIER in it such as

```
module : K_MODULE K_IDENTIFIER list_of_ports_parameters K_POINTVIRG
{cout << "the value of K_IDENTIFIER is :"<< $2.str << endl;}
list_of_module_itemsE
    K_ENDMODULE
```

fdsfds

As you can see, i would like to print the value (which is a string) of K_IDENTIFIER. This is just an example to help me understand the mechanism behind that because later i will create some c++ object and fill information in them depending on what i read.

If you need more code to see my problem, feel free to ask.
thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant to tag this with gnu-Flex and not Adobe Flex, so I retagged it.

Comment: I cleaned up your formatting a little bit. If you have a large block of code, indent it by four spaces. It's much better than trying to make the backticks work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `%union`, the `#define` for `YYSTYPE` is not necessary; that may be part of the problem. Bison will automatically pick the proper member of the union so you only need `$2` to reference the value, not `$2.str`, i.e.:

```
{ cout << "the value of K_IDENTIFIER is: " << $2 << endl; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick ! I know i should have register to stack overflow before ^^